# MAC OSX homebrew mariadb

Tags: macos, homebrew, mariadb

```
➜  ~ mysql_install_db

Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/usr/local/var/mysql' ...
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.12/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.12-MariaDB) starting as process 78349 ...
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2493223 and 2493223 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2493452 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2016-03-14 23:36:39 7fff70f51000 InnoDB: Error: page 7 log sequence number 2493499
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2493452.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
2016-03-14 23:36:39 7fff70f51000 InnoDB: Error: page 5 log sequence number 2493499
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 2493452.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2016-03-14 23:36:39 140735088496640 [ERROR] InnoDB: Creation of SYS_TABLESPACES and SYS_DATAFILES has failed with error 18.  Tablespace is full. Dropping incompletely created tables.
2016-03-14 23:36:39 7fff70f51000  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140735088496640 in file dict0crea.cc line 1901
InnoDB: Failing assertion: err == DB_OUT_OF_FILE_SPACE || err == DB_TOO_MANY_CONCURRENT_TRXS
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
160314 23:36:39 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see http://kb.askmonty.org/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.12-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=402653184
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=153
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1023017 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x48400
0   mysqld                              0x0000000101b693e3 my_print_stacktrace + 61
0   mysqld                              0x0000000101601bb9 handle_fatal_signal + 632
0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8cd47eaa _sigtramp + 26
0   ???                                 0x0000000102ac26f0 0x0 + 4339803888
0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff916c06e7 abort + 129
0   mysqld                              0x00000001019e4782 _Z40dict_create_add_tablespace_to_dictionarymPKcmS0_P5trx_tb + 0
0   mysqld                              0x0000000101b1d67d _Z34innobase_start_or_create_for_mysqlv + 9623
0   mysqld                              0x0000000101a5e51e _ZL13innobase_initPv + 2877
0   mysqld                              0x00000001016027d8 _Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int + 94
0   mysqld                              0x0000000101775701 _ZL17plugin_initializeP11st_mem_rootP13st_plugin_intPiPPcb + 349
0   mysqld                              0x00000001017753b2 _Z11plugin_initPiPPci + 2845
0   mysqld                              0x00000001016b5ca4 _ZL22init_server_componentsv + 1786
0   mysqld                              0x00000001016b4110 _Z11mysqld_mainiPPc + 10815
0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff965595ad start + 1
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/usr/local/var/mysql for more information.

The problem could be conflicting information in an external
my.cnf files. You can ignore these by doing:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.12/scripts/scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf

You can also try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.12/bin/mysqld --skip-grant --general-log &

and use the command line tool /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.12/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.12/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
--general-log gives you a log in /usr/local/var/mysql that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
MariaDB is hosted on launchpad; You can find the latest source and
email lists at http://launchpad.net/maria

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at http://mariadb.org/jira
```

I am desperate, 
I tried in every way, I also just installed mysql, but the result is the same.
Moreover also I get error "ERROR 2002" when I try to connect using the mysql client.
you have a my.cnf functioning? I tried to use my-huge.cnf support files

Comment: If you're having trouble building it, you'll probably have better luck over on the official issue tracker: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues

Comment: Did you upgrade?  Did you run `mysql_upgrade`?

Comment: The same error if i run mysql_upgrade